# Google AdSense showing blank ads on WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, adsense

I have a wordpress site  http://www.spadli.com
As adsense plugin for wordpress is deprecated. I created my adsense account. Verified the site.
Created a new ad unit and pasted its code in body tag.

Here is my ad unit code

```
<script async 
   src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
   <!-- spadli-home -->
   <ins class="adsbygoogle"
       style="display:block"
       data-ad-client="ca-pub-2760029831290185"
       data-ad-slot="8532843753"
       data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
   <script>
   (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

After adding this code nothing from google. Only blank ads.

Then I applied for upgrade (IN MY ADS -> Other Products )
It give me  code i put it in header tag.

```
<script async 
src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
  google_ad_client: "ca-pub-2760029831290185",
  enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
</script>
```

but no good luck. Nothing from google.
My hosting was a bit slow so now i have changed my hosting.
Still no message from adsense and still showing blank ads.

Can you check what i am doing wrong???
Can some one tell me how to fix it?????

Comment: is your site is in production phase, then give me the url

Comment: @SagarV 
http://www.spadli.com

Comment: From what I can see is that you implemented both the synchronous and asynchronous ad code into your webpage. Try to use one of them. https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3221666?hl=en

Comment: First of all, is your account approved to display ads? Verifying the site only won't work, once you put adsense code into your website, google will go through your website and approve/disapprove the adsense integration based on various factor.

Comment: My site is approved and i have applied for upgrade to full adsense account
It have been around month butt still nothing.(On upgrade page It shows message your site will be reviewed in 3 days.)

Comment: @AsimZaka It means, still your account approval is in progress, and not approved fully yet. Sometimes google takes more time to approve, you will receive email from google regarding status when it happens.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds likes your Adsense account is not fully approved yet.

See: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/76228

Comment: Yes my account is not fully approved yet. I have applied for upgrade o account more than a month ago.

Comment: You will have to contact Adsense support regarding that. The code is fine, it in Adsense not approving your account.

Comment: For what it's worth, this has happened to me too. I've been running AdMob ads for years but upgrading to AdSense is taking forever (over a month).

Comment: Yeah I used to use Adsense and had similar issue. :(

Answer (score -1):

Next to the Google approval process, think of the following things:

- Are you using any ad blockers in your browser?
- What are the ad space settings? One of them is 'show a blank space when no ads are available'

Please also take note of the Adsense rules:

- No different ad programs on one page
- No clicking on your own ads (also click rings are forbidden)

Answer (score -1):

When The client using `Ad Blocker` in their browser..
   Then Only the corresponding `Ad's Div` will be blank..

Just disable the adblocker..restart your Browser.